# Fatal error: RNFirebaseDatabase.on got 2 arguments, expected 3

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

### Issue

I am currently having a production issue when launching my application as I receive an error as shown below. This occurs after logging in, quitting the app, and relaunching it.

[image: screen shot 2019-02-20 at 11 21 05 am]

I believe the code below could be related as the user is logged in automatically on start if the use previously quit the application without logging out.

```
export const userProfileFetch = () => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        var user = snapshot.val();
        if(user){
          user.userId = snapshot.key;
          dispatch({ type: USER_PROFILE_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: user });
        }
      });
  };
};

export const userProfileFetch1 = () => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase1.auth();
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase1.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        var user = snapshot.val();
        if(user){
          user.userId = snapshot.key;
          dispatch({ type: USER_PROFILE_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: user });
        }
      });
  };
};

export const usersFetch = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/users`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({ type: USERS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });

      });
  };
};

export const clearUserForm = () => {
  return {
    type: USER_CREATE
  };
};


export const teamMembersFetch = (teamId) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: SHOULD_RERENDER});
    firebase.database().ref(`/users`).orderByChild("teams/" + teamId).equalTo("true")
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({ type: USERS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });

      });
  };
};


export const orderMembers = (teamId) => {
  var members = {};
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: SHOULD_NOT_RERENDER});
    firebase.database().ref(`/users`).orderByChild("teams/" + teamId).equalTo("true")
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        members = snapshot.val();

      var members2 =  _.map(members, (val, uid) => {
        return { ...val, uid };
      });
      function compare(a,b) {
        if (a.lastname < b.lastname){
          return -1;
        } else if (a.lastname > b.lastname){
          return 1;
        } else {
          if (a.firstname < b.firstname){
            return -1;
          } else if (a.firstname > b.firstname) {
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
         }
      }
      var members3 = members2.sort(compare);
      var sorted_members_obj = _.keyBy(members3, 'uid');
      dispatch({ type: USERS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: sorted_members_obj});
      });
  };
};
```

### Project Files

#### iOS

`ios/Podfile`:

- [x]  I'm not using Pods
- [] I'm using Pods and my Podfile looks like:

```rb
# N/A
```

`AppDelegate.m`:

```c
// N/A
```

#### Android

`android/build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion   = "16.3.0"
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            flatDir {
                dirs 'libs'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`android/app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.javelin"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 85
        versionName "1.0.85"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r236355'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation project(':appcenter')
    implementation project(':appcenter-analytics')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')


    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-code-push')
    implementation project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8") { force = true }  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':RNMail')
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':react-native-keychain')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    // RNFirebase required dependencies
//    compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
//      transitive = false
//    }
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

    // If you are receiving Google Play API availability issues, add the following dependency
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"

    // RNFirebase optional dependencies
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2"

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.6'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`android/settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'javelin'
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-keychain'
project(':react-native-keychain').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-keychain/android')
include ':react-native-fs'
project(':react-native-fs').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fs/android')
include ':react-native-fetch-blob'
project(':react-native-fetch-blob').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob/android')
include ':react-native-code-push'
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')
include ':appcenter-crashes'
project(':appcenter-crashes').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/appcenter-crashes/android')

include ':react-native-fbsdk'
project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')
include ':react-native-image-picker'
project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
include ':react-native-image-picker'
project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
include ':appcenter-analytics'
project(':appcenter-analytics').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/appcenter-analytics/android')
include ':appcenter'
project(':appcenter').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/appcenter/android')
include ':react-native-code-push'
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')
include ':react-native-fetch-blob'
project(':react-native-fetch-blob').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob/android')
include ':react-native-fs'
project(':react-native-fs').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fs/android')
include ':react-native-keychain'
project(':react-native-keychain').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-keychain/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
include ':RNMail'
project(':RNMail').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-mail/android')

include ':app'
```

`MainApplication.java`:

```
package com.javelin;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.chirag.RNMail.RNMail;
import com.oblador.keychain.KeychainPackage;
import com.rnfs.RNFSPackage;
import com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;

import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.microsoft.appcenter.reactnative.analytics.AppCenterReactNativeAnalyticsPackage;
import com.microsoft.appcenter.reactnative.appcenter.AppCenterReactNativePackage;
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;
import com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;
import com.rnfs.RNFSPackage;

import com.oblador.keychain.KeychainPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;

import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

// Required package
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage; // <-- Add this line
// Optional packages - add as appropriate
import io.invertase.firebase.analytics.RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage; // Firebase Analytics
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage; // Firebase Auth
import io.invertase.firebase.config.RNFirebaseRemoteConfigPackage; // Firebase Remote Config
import io.invertase.firebase.fabric.crashlytics.RNFirebaseCrashlyticsPackage; // Firebase Crash Reporting
import io.invertase.firebase.database.RNFirebaseDatabasePackage; // Firebase Realtime Database
import io.invertase.firebase.storage.RNFirebaseStoragePackage; // Firebase Storage
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.links.RNFirebaseLinksPackage;

import com.chirag.RNMail.*;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;

  }

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {

        @Override
        protected String getJSBundleFile() {
        return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
        }





    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
            new ImagePickerPackage(),
            new AppCenterReactNativeAnalyticsPackage(MainApplication.this, getResources().getString(R.string.appcenterAnalytics_whenToEnableAnalytics)),
            new AppCenterReactNativePackage(MainApplication.this),
            new CodePush(getResources().getString(R.string.reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey), getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.DEBUG),
            new RNFetchBlobPackage(),
            new RNMail(),
            new RNFSPackage(),
            new KeychainPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new RNFirebasePackage(),
            // Add these packages as appropriate
            new RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage(),
            new RNFirebaseAuthPackage(),
            new RNFirebaseRemoteConfigPackage(),
            new RNFirebaseCrashlyticsPackage(),
            new RNFirebaseDatabasePackage(),
            new RNFirebaseStoragePackage(),
            new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage(),
            new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
              new RNFirebaseLinksPackage()


      );


    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }

}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.javelin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       >

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>



       <service
          android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />      


        <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseLocalMessagingPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
                  <!-- android:pathPrefix="/events"  -->
            <data android:scheme="https"
                  android:host="rd54z.app.goo.gl"
                  />
          <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="rd54z.app.goo.gl"
                />
            <data android:scheme="rd54z.app.goo.gl/?link=https"
                  android:host="javelinsportsinc.com"
                  />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I currently have no idea as to what is causing the issue. The 'on' method itself normally requires 2 arguments. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help.

Comment: Just hit this. did you find anything in the end?